# getElementsByTagName only get top level tags?

Tags: javascript

i have this really weired js problem.

in summary, i get a element not found if i use `(document.getElementsByTagName("p"))[0]`

and if the `p` tag is inside a `div` like this

```
<div id="main">
<p>see</p>
</div>
```

but as soon as i remove the div wrapper, all things work.

after 30 min, i've reduced the problem to this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ttttttttttttttttttttt</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<p>see</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myobj = document.createElement("div");
myobj.innerHTML='yesyes';

document.body.insertBefore(myobj, (document.getElementsByTagName("p"))[0] );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

put above in a file. Open in Firefox or Chrome or IE8. If successful, you should see “yesyes”.
If you remove the `<div id="main">` wrapper, then it works.

it seems there something i'm not understanding about `getElementsByTagName`??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing to do with `getElementsByTagName`, everything to do with `insertBefore`. Try this:

```
document.getElementById('main').insertBefore(myobj, (document.getElementsByTagName("p"))[0] );​​
```

`insertBefore` needs the parent element. It won't function the way you are calling it (on `body`), so I just looked up the "main" div instead.

Comment: +1 Specifically, the problem is that the `refChild` is not found in the element on which he's calling `insertBefore`.

Comment: Another possibility would be `var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0]; p.parentNode.insertBefore(myObj, p);`

Comment: I'd use Felix's version, as the intent appears to be to not rely on the "main" ID.

Comment: Definitely better to use parentNode.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with `document.body.insertBefore`, not with `document.getElementsByTagName` -- you can see this for yourself by sticking the line

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML);
```

at the beginning of the script.

So what's going on with [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore)?  It is a method of *all* DOM nodes, as you can see at that link, and it will only insert an element (or "document fragment") before one of the *direct children* of that node.  When you have `<div id="main>` in there, the `<p>` found by `getElementsByTagName` is not a direct child of the `<body>`, so `body.insertBefore` will not do what you want.

To get the effect you want, use instead

```
var first_p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
first_p.parentNode.insertBefore(myobj, first_p);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the parent element, not `document.body` for `.insertBefore`.

```
<div id="main"><p>see</p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myobj = document.createElement("div");
myobj.innerHTML='yesyes';

document.getElementById('main').insertBefore(myobj, document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0] );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to append child myobj before inserting it into body

```
document.body.appendChild(myobj);
```

Comment: No, that's what he's trying to do with `insertBefore`.